# How does one copy commits without producing different SHA1s?

Tags: git, patch, git-branch, git-rebase, git-patch

As much as I've tried to avoid it, I have to maintain three `master`-equivalient branches with minor changes in each one. I've been reading about `git` and using it for a couple of years, so I'm familiar with the following conventional wisdom:

1. Don't `merge` unless it is meaningful. Use `rebase` instead.
2. If you just need to pull in one commit, `cherry-pick` is your friend.
3. Always `pull --rebase` on the remote before pushing.
4. Keep features in line with `rebase`.

What they don't tell you is the conventional wisdom creates a bunch of commits that are *nearly* identical, except for minor details that change their SHA1s. Why does this matter? It defeats the purpose of comparing branches with `git log --left-right --graph --cherry-pick --oneline branch1..branch2` and `git show-branch`, which is especially annoying. Feels like an *abuse* of cheap branching. It makes it nearly impossible to see which patches are missing from each branch.

So, how do you keep multiple branches in line with identical SHA1s so these tools can be used? Are patches the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot keep commits with identical SHAs in multiple places because **the "place" of a commit** (its location in history) **is identified by the SHA**.

A Git commit contains certain data, among them a snapshot of the current repo state, the current time and date, the committer name and email, **and the SHA of the parent commit(s)**.

That means that when you put a commit somewhere else (`rebase`, `cherry-pick`, patch+apply) or change its time (`commit --amend`), *the SHA will be different.*

This is a significant feature of Git (Git history is a so-called [Merkle tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree)).

As you have noticed, you can maintain *(content-)equivalent* commits by using the various history-rewrite commands I mentioned above.

---

Depending on your situation, you *might* be able to use the commits which are in `master` without having to copy them. If those changes that make your "`master`-equivalent" branches different are purely additive (i.e. they occur in commits which can always be *appended* to the latest commit in master), then you can just always rebase your other branches onto `master` and be happy, because then they simply contain all of `master`'s commits exactly as they are.

If your changes are, on the other hand, of a kind which requires to be inserted earlier in history (i.e. new commits to `master` *must* be appended *after* your differentiating changes), then you will not be able to keep a "nice" history like that.

I can't spontaneously think of an example of the second situation, but it's theoretically possible (be it actually required by the content, or required by external factors like project specifications).

Comment: Thanks, this is actually the way I should have been keeping master-equivalents in line the whole time. History is clean, comparisons work as expected, DAG looks nice. For those finding this in the future, I'll just note that for me, `master` was general and `master-foo` was specific. So after testing changes in `master`, commit and then switch to `master-foo` and rebase. That plops `master-foo`'s commits on top. It's helpful also to push by doing `git rebase -i @{u} && git push origin HEAD` to avoid overwriting remote history.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure `git rebase -i @{u} && git push origin HEAD` is the way to go. Something in my workflow is reordering my commits, and that might be it. Anyway, @nevik's advice is solid.

Comment: if you want to rebase all of the commits in `master-foo`, you dont need an interactive rebase (you can use it to check which commits will be rebased, though); and if rebasing onto `@{u}` works, `git push` will be sufficient because your branch is set up to track its upstream branch (**unless** your `push.default` setting tells Git to push *all* tracking branches)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is conventional wisdom to not merge unless it is meaningful. If you want the keep history with identical SHA1 hashes, merge, and avoid cherry-picking.

Answer (score 0):

I think some of the premises of the question are wrong.

Git uses a content-addressable database because (among other things) it
wants to protect the integrity of the version history. And every little
piece of commit metadata counts towards the SHA1, hence why it changes
every time.

On the other hand… Git is distributed and lets you work with distributed
workflows. Like sending patches via email. [1] And patches aren’t commits
(snapshots). So you end up with a two-level system:

1. Published history
2. In-flight changes (email patches, that patch stack that you’ve been
   maintaing for two years because the upstream hasn’t accepted it yet,
   …)

And you deal with that by (respectively):

1. You compare branches, tags, etc. by looking at their commits; you
   should have *the same commits*, not almost-identical ones

   - A corollary is that you merge things rather than cherry-pick or
     rebase when working within the published history
2. You use `git cherry` and other commands in order to compare commits
   using their *patch id* (basically a diff normalization; compare the
   changes that commits introduce)

So these are two ways of working with history (stable and in-flight,
respectively)—using merges etc. and overall treating changes as
immutable is far more ergonomic for stable, published history. On the
other hand, treating changes as “patches” is simply necessary for
in-flight history in certain workflows. But, in my opinion, using
in-flight history tools on stable history will just make your life
harder for very little benefit. You might save yourself from having to
do a few extra merges, but in the end you can live with having those
merges in your history.

#### Notes

1. We could also go into rebase workflows but it’s easier to pick an
   example which *necessitates* using things like `git cherry` since you
   can’t do a `git merge` on patch emails